# How to open another <div> when an item in list clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a SPA application. I have to different div for pageView and pageDetail. I will retrieve data from SQlite database and display in listview under pageView. If an item from the list is clicked, then it should load pageDetail and do some function there. Currently, I can retrieve data from SQlite and display in listview. I also able to click the item, I tested using alert. I tried using pagecontainer load but it did not work. How can I load pageDetail when the item is clicked and how can I run a function when the pageDetail is loaded?

HTML div- #pageView and #pageDetail

```
   <div data-role="page" id="pageView">
    <div data-role="header">

        <h2>View</h2>
        <button type="button" id="buttonView">View</button>
    </div>
    <!-- main -->
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

        <ul id="listData" data-role="listview">
        </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- footer -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h2>myproject</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="pageDetail">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#pageView" class="ui-btn ui-icon-back">Back</a>
        <h2>Details</h2>

    </div>
    <!-- main -->
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">


    </div>
    <!-- footer -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h2>myproject</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#pageView').on('click', '#listData li', function(){
 var myeve = $(this).find('#selectedEve').text();
 $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "load", $('#pageDetail'), { 
 showLoadMsg: false } );

});

('#pageDetail').on("pageshow", function() {

//do some function here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just need a redirect.

```
window.location.href = "http://YourSite.com/#PageDetail";
```

Else you could try to not display the PageDetail on  loading with **display:none** and do a **display:block** onClick?

If you want to get the pageDetail loaded after you clicked the item, i suggest u make an ajax-call for it that returns the requested html and then output it in your container

I'm not sure yet what you are trying to get done, so this is just a wild goose..

Comment: my pageView and pageDetail is in the same html file. I just need to open another div if the item from list clicked.

Comment: Then use the id of your pageDetails to .show() or .hide() if you have jquery. Else you need to access the requested divs css to switch the display option

Comment: it works when use .show() and .hide(). But I messed up my UI. It just showing in normal html view. My jquery buttons all not working.